# What is the major difference between system contract and other contracts?

Tags: eosio.token

What is the difference  between defining actions inside a eosio contract such  as eosio.token and other contracts.

Can I costomize the eosio contract : for example can I customize the eosio.token contract according to my use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases, the contract of custom tokens are based on `eosio.token` contract. You can add custom actions, or change the logic of existing actions such as create, issue, transfer and so on.

The main difference of `eosio.system` contract and others is that `eosio.system` is for privileged account, so it contains privileged APIs like `setpriv` etc. (Privileged APIs are not callable by normal account and you can find them from `eosiolib/privileged.h`)

Comment: Can we customize  the eosio.token contract according to our requirement?

Comment: Why not? Customize as you want, and deploy it on your account. If you mean the contract deployed on`eosio.token`account, it’s not possible. Only the majority of block producers can have a permission to modify it.

Comment: Yes it seems  fine.